# How to load a web page using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to load a web page in WPF and interact with the elements in the page. Is there a way to do this with WPF?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try use the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx) control. This basically provides you with a web browser inside your app and you can then load and navigate through web pages.

Just place the control with

```
<WebBrowser Name="webBrowser" />
```

and then

```
webBrowser.Navigate("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
<WebBrowser Source="http://www.microsoft.com" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a WebBrowser control to your WPF and load a web page using the Navigate method:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
```